# Prove that $x^2 - 2013^2 \le y \le 2013^2 - x^2$ has an odd number of solutions

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

$x$ and $y$ are integers. $N$ is the number of solutions $(x, y)$ of this inequation $x^2 - 2013^2 \le y \le 2013^2 - x^2$. Prove that N is odd.

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$?

Comment: They are integers

Comment: Or perhaps he means that, for each x, there are an odd number of y such that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ be any solution for the inequalities

$$x^2 - 2013^2 \le y \le 2013^2 - x^2\tag{*1}$$

It is clear

- $|y| \le 2013^2 - x^2 \le 2013^2$
- $x^2 - 2013^2 \le 2013^2 - x^2 \iff 0 \le 2013^2 - x^2 \iff |x| \le 2013$

From these, we can conclude $N$, the number of solutions for $(*1)$, is finite.

Notice

- If $(x,y)$ is a solution, so does $(-x,-y)$.
- $(0,0)$ is a solution.

This implies aside from $(0,0)$, all other solutions of $(*1)$ can be grouped in pairs. As a result, $N$ is odd.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the LHS is an up parabola that has roots at $\pm 2013$.  The RHS is also a down parabola with roots at $\pm 2013$.  Which values of $y$ satisfy the inequality?

Answer (score 1):

For any $A$ the inequality $-A \le y \le A$ has an odd number of solutions, since $0$ is one solution and other solutions come in pairs $(-t,t)$ where $t \neq 0.$ So if $x$ in your problem is any fixed integer, there are an odd number of solutions. On the other hand if $x$ is allowed to be just any integer there are infinitely many solutions, which is not odd or even.

Comment: @achillehui Yes I agree with you that given there are solutions, the $x$ ends up bounded, so a finite number of $y$ in such a case. Of course if $x^2<2013^2$ there are no solutions to the OP inequality, and to be picky $0$ is even not odd, so I assume that wasn't the case.